# Axios accidentelly sort response data alphabetically

Tags: reactjs, axios, request

I'm very new in React and I need to display data from axios response. It should be in order that is in db, but strangely axios sort my data alphabetically. I check my backend returning data and it's normal.
For example original data is:

```
{
  profession: 'doctor',
  car: 'Honda',
  age: 45,
}
```

But I got this

```
{
  age: 45,
  car: 'Honda',
  profession: 'doctor',
}
```

React Component

```
function SearchForm({reqForms}) {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const fetchForms = async (data) => {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/forms/filtered", data)
    console.log(res)
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(fetchForms)} className={styles.searchBar}>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        {...register("profession")} 
      />
      <button>Search</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Maybe you know, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on object property order is not advised (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/10718641) for more on this).  If you wish to have the data displayed in a certain way, you can

1. use the object properties in ordered columns (ie `data.age`)
2. return an array of properties from your backend (ie `[{ age: 45 }, { car: 'honda' }, ...`

There are other options, but these are the most direct and deterministic.